# Tensorflow-Lite pretrained model does not work in Android demo

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Tensorflow-Lite Android demo works with the original model it provides: mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite. See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite

They also provide other pretrained lite models here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/models.md

However, I downloaded some of the smaller models from the above link, for example, mobilenet_v1_0.25_224.tflite, and replaced the original model with this model in the demo app by just changing the `MODEL_PATH = "mobilenet_v1_0.25_224.tflite";` in the `ImageClassifier.java`. The app crashes with:

> 12-11 12:52:34.222 17713-17729/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   CameraBackground
>                                                      Process: android.example.com.tflitecamerademo, PID: 17713
>                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to get input dimensions.
>   0-th input should have 602112 bytes, but found 150528 bytes.
>                                                          at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.getInputDims(Native
>   Method)
>                                                          at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:82)
>                                                          at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:112)
>                                                          at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:93)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.classifyFrame(ImageClassifier.java:108)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.classifyFrame(Camera2BasicFragment.java:663)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.access$900(Camera2BasicFragment.java:69)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment$5.run(Camera2BasicFragment.java:558)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

The reason seems to be that the input dimension required by the model is four times larger than the image size. So I modified `DIM_BATCH_SIZE = 1` to `DIM_BATCH_SIZE = 4`. Now the error is:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
>                                                      Process: android.example.com.tflitecamerademo, PID: 18241
>                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert an TensorFlowLite
>   tensor with type FLOAT32 to a Java object of type [[B (which is
>   compatible with the TensorFlowLite type UINT8)
>                                                          at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:36)
>                                                          at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:122)
>                                                          at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:93)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.classifyFrame(ImageClassifier.java:108)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.classifyFrame(Camera2BasicFragment.java:663)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.access$900(Camera2BasicFragment.java:69)
>                                                          at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment$5.run(Camera2BasicFragment.java:558)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

**My question is how to get a reduced-MobileNet tflite model to work with the TF-lite Android Demo.**

(I actually tried other things, like convert a TF frozen graph to TF-lite model using the provided tool, even using exactly same example code as in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md, but the converted tflite model still can not work in the Android Demo.)

Comment: Can you please state a clear question in the body of the post (not just the title)? Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Just a note that I'm also experiencing this. Curiously, those same retrained models work fine for me when I drop them into the demo app for Tensorflow for Poets 2 Lite (which shares a lot of code with the Tensorflow-Android Lite demo referenced by OP. https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tree/master/android/tflite

Answer (score 4):

The ImageClassifier.java included with Tensorflow-Lite Android demo expects a **quantized** model. As of right now, only one of the Mobilenets models is provided in quantized form: *Mobilenet 1.0 224 Quant*.

To use the other float models, swap in the ImageClassifier.java from the Tensorflow for Poets TF-Lite demo source. This is written for **float** models.
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/android/tflite/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifier.java

Do a diff and you'll see there are several important differences in implementation.

Another option to consider is converting the float models to quantized using TOCO:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md

Comment: Thanks very much. The Tensorflow for Poets works! For your second option, I previously quantized some MobileNet model which worked in Android TF demo as a .pb file. But now if I using TOCO to convert such quantized model to .tflite model, there are some issues during conversion. I think the fatal one is Unsupported TensorFlow op: Dequantize. Have you also experienced this?

Comment: Yes I haven't had any luck yet converting quantized models to .tflite

Comment: There are now quantized mobilenet v1 models for all depth_mulitpliers and image sizes. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md

Comment: @AshEldritch "converting the float models to quantized using TOCO" needs instrumenting the graph with quantized nodes before passing to Toco.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same errors as Seedling was getting.
I have created a new Image classifier wrapper for Mobilenet Float model.
It's working fine now. You can directly add this class in image classifier demo and use this to create classifier in Camera2BasicFragment

```
classifier = new ImageClassifierFloatMobileNet(getActivity());
```

below is the Image classifier class wrapper for Mobilenet Float model

```
    /**
 * This classifier works with the Float MobileNet model.
 */
public class ImageClassifierFloatMobileNet extends ImageClassifier {

  /**
   * An array to hold inference results, to be feed into Tensorflow Lite as outputs.
   * This isn't part of the super class, because we need a primitive array here.
   */
  private float[][] labelProbArray = null;

  private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
  private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128.0f;

  /**
   * Initializes an {@code ImageClassifier}.
   *
   * @param activity
   */
  public ImageClassifierFloatMobileNet(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    super(activity);
    labelProbArray = new float[1][getNumLabels()];
  }

  @Override
  protected String getModelPath() {
    // you can download this file from
    // https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/mobilenet_v1_224_android_quant_2017_11_08.zip
//    return "mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite";
    return "retrained.tflite";
  }

  @Override
  protected String getLabelPath() {
//    return "labels_mobilenet_quant_v1_224.txt";
    return "retrained_labels.txt";
  }

  @Override
  public int getImageSizeX() {
    return 224;
  }

  @Override
  public int getImageSizeY() {
    return 224;
  }

  @Override
  protected int getNumBytesPerChannel() {
    // the Float model uses a 4 bytes
    return 4;
  }

  @Override
  protected void addPixelValue(int val) {
    imgData.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
  }

  @Override
  protected float getProbability(int labelIndex) {
    return labelProbArray[0][labelIndex];
  }

  @Override
  protected void setProbability(int labelIndex, Number value) {
    labelProbArray[0][labelIndex] = value.byteValue();
  }

  @Override
  protected float getNormalizedProbability(int labelIndex) {
    return labelProbArray[0][labelIndex];
  }

  @Override
  protected void runInference() {
    tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArray);
  }
}
```